# Errors are known to occur in 0.9% of hard disks. In a sample of 5 hard disks, what is the probability that 4 or more are found to be error-free?

Tags: probability

> Hard disk error is most common non-accidental cause of data loss. A large company checks a random sample of its computers each month for hard disk errors. Errors are known to occur in $0.9\%$ of hard-disks. In a sample of $5$ hard disks, what is the probability that $4$ or more are found to be error-free?

What I got for my answer is $0.9907$ or $0.991$

Adding it from $k= 0$ to $k = 4$, where $n = 5$, $k = 4$, $p = 0.009$ from $0.9\%$.

Please provide a Feedback on my solution, whether its correct or wrong ,thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  What do you know about a binomial distribution?  Does it help?

Comment: yes i kinda know a bit of it , but got confused on the percentage part

Comment: $0.9\% = 0.009$

Comment: @RossMillikan 
i have edited my answer , please provide a feed back , thanks

Comment: I get $(5)(0.991)^4(0.009)+(0.991)^5$, which I think is about $0.9992$.

Answer (score 1):

We'll assume that errors occur independently with probability $p=0.9\%=0.009$ (which might be argued as reasonable since the company is "large").  This means the number of errors is [binomially distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), i.e., for $0 \leq i \leq 5$, we have $$\mathrm{Pr}[\text{exactly } i \text{ errors}]=\binom{5}{i} p^i(1-p)^{5-i}.$$

The other piece of the puzzle needed to solve this problem is $$\mathrm{Pr}[\geq 4 \text{ error-free}] = \mathrm{Pr}[\text{exactly } 0 \text{ errors}]+\mathrm{Pr}[\text{exactly } 1 \text{ error}].$$

My computation of this quantity disagrees with the proposed answers.

Comment: Sorry, I still dont get your formula, can you get a bit more detailed?

Comment: The first formula is the probability mass function for the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  It gives the probability of *exactly* $i$ errors, where $i$ could be any number in $\{0,1,\ldots,5\}$.  The second formula comes about since $\geq 4$ disks being error-free is the same as $\leq 1$ disks containing an error, which is the same as exactly $0$ errors or exactly $1$ error.

Comment: Thanks, understanding it a bit