# Probability of at most one event happening

Tags: probability

There are n independent disks that have error probability $P_1, P_2, \ldots P_n$. Now, what is the probability that "at most" 1 disk will have an error?

It will be great if I can get a general formula for "at most m" disk but right now formula for 1 disk will be enough.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898848/errors-are-known-to-occur-in-0-9-of-hard-disks-in-a-sample-of-5-hard-disks-wh) is almost identical to mine but in case of that it is assumed every disk will have the same error probability which is not true in my case. I am not sure if I can use binomial theory to solve my problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It is the probability that disk one has an error (but no others do), plus the probability that disk two has an error (but no others do), plus...

Comment: do you mean 
p1*(1-p2)*(1-p3)*...(1-pn) + (1-p1)*p2*(1-p3)*...(1-pn)+....... + (1-p1)*(1-p2)*....pn

Answer (score 2):

$P = P_1 \prod\limits_{i \neq 1}^n (1-P_i) + P_2 \prod\limits_{i\neq 2}^n (1-P_i) + \cdots = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left( P_k \prod\limits_{i \neq k}^n (1-P_i)\right)$

Comment: thank you very much. Is it possible to extend this formula for "at most m" errors?

Comment: @MasudulHasan:  Gosh... not even an upvote (let alone an acceptance), and you ask for *another* answer?!

Comment: I gave an upvote. Unfortunately, I don't have the necessary "reputation" for that upvote to be displayed. I am not sure what do you mean by "acceptance" though.

Comment: "Acceptance" means clicking on the $\color{green}\Huge{\checkmark}$ indicating that a solution answers the question as posed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. Btw, your solution doesn't include the case of "No error". Your solution is right for "exactly one error" not "at most one". But thank you very much for the solution. It helped to get the right one.